# Error type go lang

Tags: go

Is error type in Go "Error" or "error"? It bugged me that in the [Tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/19) it is with small first letter so I looked around and found [here with small e](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) yet [here in source code](https://golang.org/src/runtime/error.go) it is with big capital letter.
Also how can it be without big capital letter yet still visible outside of package?

Just started learning Go so I might have missed something basic, thanks.

Comment: So I tried it and I can't have type `Error` even when `runtime` package is imported and it says that `imported and not used: "runtime"`

Comment: It is *error* all lowercase, as it is a predeclared type as explained here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors

Comment: `runtime.Error` is a different type than `error`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`error` is the type, lowercase. Just like with `int` and `string` it doesn't need to be visible as it is built-in to Go:

[A good blog post on error handling](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)

The `runtime` package you're referring to has an `Error` interface. The type there is an *interface* not *error*:

[Package runtime](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Error)

```
type Error interface {
    error

    // RuntimeError is a no-op function but
    // serves to distinguish types that are run time
    // errors from ordinary errors: a type is a
    // run time error if it has a RuntimeError method.
    RuntimeError()
}
```

> The Error interface identifies a run time error.